# Graph Theory - Connectivity of r-regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Hello everyone. I'm really struggling with this question. All help appreciated.

Find the minimum positive integer r for which there exists an r-regular graph G such that λ(G) ≥ κ(G) + 2

I know it's not 1,2,3-regular since κ(G) = λ(G) for those graphs.

Comment: This is a homework question:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.andrew.cmu.edu%2Fuser%2Fjnir%2F21-484%2Fex3_template.tex&ei=eJmCT4m2KMTIrQfx75HsBQ&usg=AFQjCNG5jS3eaIvj13x5dR9-BkbrxqUUGA

Comment: Actually it's an exercise from Chartrand & Lesniak Ex2.4 Q.16, and it's not homework.

Comment: I'd suggest you put such question on http://math.stackexchange.com . 

Comment: Just consider all the possibilities, there are very few.

Answer (score 1):

Take tow disjoint copies of the complete graph on 5 vertices. Pick a vertex on each of the copy and split into tow vertices of degree 2. Match the the degree 2 vertices of both copies the identify them to get 4-regular,  4-egde-connected, and 2-vertex-connected graph.